# How to make an AJAX request to Dictionary.com's REST API using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Dictionary.com provides absolutely no documentation on how to grab data from them.  I'm trying to use jQuery's ajax requests, but those are not working.

They provide a URL through which I'm supposed to be able to use.  I'll provide this below.

```
http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001?vid=<VID>&type=random&site=dictionary
```

They also provide a key, which I assume that I place in the `<VID>` spot.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with this?  I'll provide the code I'm using below:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api-pub.dictionary.com/",
    type: "GET",
    data: "v001?vid=<VID>&type=random&site=dictionary",
    success: function() { alert("success") },
  });

});
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you replacing `<VID>` in your code?  Is your VID valid?  Have you tried submitting to the exact URL in `url` parameter (instead of writing the query string in the `data` parameter)?

Comment: Did you check the network inspector to find out what HTTP error code you're getting? Install an error callback? Since it's a get you can just type it into the URL box. -1 for a question without error messages, I'll remove it when you add that information, hey, you'll probably answer your own question after you look at those things

Comment: Are you trying to leverage their "Word of the Day" tool, or is this for something else?

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing the data correctly. Also the request url is `http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001`. Try this:

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",  //For external apis
    data: {"vid": <VID>,
          "type":"random"
          "site": "dictionary"},
    success: function() { 
       alert("success") },
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:** Maybe you're being blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as @thordarson note, in that case add:
`dataType: "jsonp"` to your ajax call.

Comment: @TomSarduy Passing `dataType: 'jsonp'` is not enough. Configuration is needed on _both_ servers. See my update.

Comment: @thordarson: I think this is not the case, the API is there for the people, I have done this with others sources ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy Dictionary.com's API isn't exactly public and there are no traces of the required headers. See my second update.

Comment: @thordarson: I see your point, but remember that you need to pass a valid `VID`

Comment: I'm replacing VID, I just placed <VID> in the example because I couldn't show the key to the public.

Comment: @JaPerk14: SO, still not working?? maybe you can add some extra info, what http response you got?

Comment: @JaPerk14 If you want to hide the key, placing it in a piece of JavaScript code is _not_ a good idea. By doing that you are in fact violating the TOS of the API.

Answer (score 3):

## Possibility 1

You don't have access to their API. According to their [API page](http://content.dictionary.com/api?__utma=1.480045750.1358727224.1358727224.1359783921.2&__utmb=1.1.10.1359783921&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1358727224.1.1.utmcsr=google%257cutmccn=%28organic%29%257cutmcmd=organic%257cutmctr=%28not%252520provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=64341935) they're very selective about who they give access to their API.

> We are selective about our API partners and approve use as well as
>   develop terms on a case-by-case basis. If you are interested in using
>   our API, please contact us directly [...].

## Possibility 2

You're being blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Browsers are generally very strict about requests made by JavaScript across different domains. This can be bypassed using [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing). This requires configuring the server you're requesting, so in this case it's not viable.

Your best bet would be to create a server-side script that requests the URL and then using AJAX to request the file.

**Example in PHP, let's call this `request_dictionary.php`:**

```
<?php

    $vid = "Your API key";
    $type = $_GET['type'];
    $site = $_GET['dictionary'];

    $request_url = "http://api-pub.dictionary.com/v001?vid=$vid&type=$type&site=$site";

    echo file_get_contents($request_url);

?>
```

**Note:** You probably need to change this to fit your needs (error handling, 404s, caching etc.). *This code is untested.*

**Then change your jQuery so that it requests your file.**

```
$("#btnGetData").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/request_dictionary.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: "type=random&site=dictionary",
    success: function() { alert("success") },
  });

});
```

## Warning

Using an AJAX call without a proxy (as explained in *possibility 2*) will expose your API key. This is against [Dictionary.com's API Terms of Service](http://developer.dictionary.com/help/terms).

> 2.1   Dictionary.com will assign and deliver to your Customer Application an Application Key to access the API. All Calls must
>   contain such Application Key. The Application Key is uniquely
>   associated with each Customer Application and all versions, upgrades
>   and updates thereof. **The Application Key is Confidential Information
>   as defined in these Terms and Conditions. You must maintain and keep
>   the Application Key in a secure, embedded manner not accessible by any
>   third party.** The Application Key is fully revocable by Dictionary.com
>   at any time. Dictionary.com may block attempts to access the API with
>   an invalid or revoked Application Key.

I've updated the code in *possibility 2* to conceal the API key by keeping it in the PHP file.

---

**Update/Note:** Simply passing `dataType: 'jsonp'` to enable cross-origin calls is not enough. The responding server needs to respond with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing your domain (or a rule that includes your domain). Any configuration of this kind is out of your hand as the requester.

**Update/Note 2:** Upon investigating the returned headers from your request URL, I can see no evidence of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. This means that even if you had access to their API, you wouldn't be able to access it using AJAX. Full headers below:

```
GET /v001?vid=%3CVID%3E&type=random&site=dictionary HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host:            api-pub.dictionary.com[CRLF]
Connection:      close[CRLF]
User-Agent:      Web-sniffer/1.0.44 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8[CRLF]
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8[CRLF]
Accept-Charset:  ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control:   no-cache[CRLF]
Referer:         http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
```